# How can kubernetes pods discover each other?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to implement something like the etcd services that uses the consensus algorithm (https://raft.github.io/). In this case, multiple instances of the etcd services need to be aware of each other. For this to happen, if we have 3 pods of etcd instance in a replication controller, the pods need to be able to talk to each other (at least be able to know the IP of self and all the other pods).

Is there a way of achieving this in the replication controller or pod specs without having to use the kubernetes API in the pod container?

Answer (score 4):

You can put a service in front of those pods by giving each pod some label (for example `etcd-service=true`), and making a kubernetes service with a selector that matches that label.  Use the DNS add-on, and you will get a DNS A record for each endpoint in the service.  You can read more in the docs [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#discovering-services).

Comment: Thanks Paul. But How do the pods in the service know about each other? Putting a service in front of the pods let us round robin between the pods but we want the pods to be aware of each other. I dont see a way to communicate the IPs of the other pods in the ETCD service to a pod

Comment: Gopinath, pods in the service can use the same discovery methods -- does that give you what you need?

Comment: Paul, Not really. Do you mean that the Pods should use the k8s APIs to discover other pods in its replication controller? For instance if there are 3 etcd pods in a etcd replication controller, how would pod 1 know about the IPs of Pod 2 and 3? Is there any way of passing the IPs of pod 2 and 3 to pod one without having to use the k8s API inside the pod? Is there any config or spec magic in YAML or JSON that lets us do it?

Comment: Gopinath, you don't need to use the kube API, all you need is DNS.

Comment: Paul, can you elaborate? According to the [DNS addon documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/dns), names are assigned to kubernetes services only. Do they have entries for Pods as well? If so, that seems to be in contradiction with what the DNS documentation says. What am I missing here?

Comment: Gopinath, I guess it's a little buried in the documentation, but check out: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md#headless-services ; note: the DNS A records are returned for each endpoint in any service not just headless ones.  If you still have questions maybe we can meet up on slack or use the chat feature on SO for higher-bandwidth comms :)

Comment: Thanks Paul. Serendipity! I posted on the "kubernetes users" channel on slack. Still waiting for a response :(. About the quote you mention, are you saying "each endpoint" actually refers to pods in a service? I did not know SO had chat. It would be great if we could chat. Thanks!

Comment: Gopinath, what's your slack nick? mine is pmorie, hit me up